# How to fetch Number of pages of excel sheet having comments at end of page

Tags: excel, comments

Excel Object Model gives us number of pages on a sheet using api Sheet->PageSetup->Pages->Count

But this count doesn't include the number of pages added because of Comments, which are printed at end of sheet ( a setting that can be made in pagesetup of a sheet)

Can someone please find a resolution to this.

Thanks
Himanshu

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? In 2003, I don't see that `PageSetup` has a `Pages` property...

Comment: @Jean: I am using Excel 2007 and Excel 2010. Both have the Pages Property in Pagesetup. if it aint there in 2003, then how do you find num pages there

Answer (score 0):

do the page breaks appear correctly in Excel display?

if so, you can try this code:

```
Sub HowManyPagesBreaks()
    Dim iHpBreaks As Integer, iVBreaks As Integer
    Dim iTotPages As Integer

    iHpBreaks = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    iVBreaks = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1

    iTotPages = iHpBreaks * iVBreaks

    MsgBox "This sheet will require " & iTotPages & _
    " page(s) to print", vbInformation, "OzGrid.com"
End Sub
```

found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/printed-pages.htm)

Comment: No the page-breaks create page boundaries as per sheet content excluding comments. So this doesn't work...

Comment: This method won't even give correct number of pages in case of sheets not having comments... Because Excel always tries to minimize the number of Blank pages in the end. For example there can be a case where number of Hpbreaks = 2 and vPbreaks = 2, Even then the total page count is 5. It is a very very basic concept in Excel.